# PEM, DER, X509, ASN.1, Oh My. Where to start?

Tags: cryptography, certificate, x509, asn.1

I'm trying to get an understanding of the world of cryptography as its practically used day to day. I'm finding it very hard to get a start footing, And I was wondering if anyone has some good resources that explain things assuming that I know nothing.

For example, I have (I believe, due to limited understanding) a file with X509 certificate and a "SignatureValue" attribute. I think these are encoded with SHA256. I would like to understand exactly what I'm looking at however, because I need to provide a "Timestamp Response File", which contains the DER representation of one Timestamp Authority Message.

Things I somewhat grasp so far:

- SHA256 is a hashing algorithm. One way?
- X509 is a document that defines how a certificate (whatever that is) should look
- ASN.1 is a group of ways to transmit data between systems?
- DER is a way of representing data in binary/octal bits.

I'd like a birds eye view of this ecosystem just so I have some concept of how this puzzle fits together, then I can delve better into the nitty gritty of How-Things-Work.

Answer (score 5):

Reading whole bunch of books will take a lot of time. 
Imho, the faster way would be to browse Wikipedia and read what is:

- hash algorithm (in short, it transform long text/data to fixed-size value, hash, which (almost) unique represents this long text. And, yes, it is one-way.
- signature algorithm - calculates something from hash value, which is called 'signature'. The main idea is that correct signature can be calculated only when you have secret key. And, this signature can be verified with public key. Public key is shared amongst people so they can verify your signatures.

So, valid signature proves that text/data was not changed by somebody else.

- certificate: this is block of data, which binds user's public key to information about this key: name of the owner, email, address, whatever else. Certificate usually signed by authority (root certificate) - so, if you trust to authority, you should believe that this certificate correctly represents person.
- timestamp: this is signature, made by some authority people trust to, which binds time mark to signature, made over other document. So, this will prove that this signature (and, this document) was correct at that time. This is needed since sometimes certificates can become revoked or outdated, and without timestamp you will not know if this is correct signature since you will not know when it was created.
- ASN.1 - Abstract Syntax Notation, it defines text rules which describe format of some data structures. It is used in most of cryptography standards.
- DER encoding (Distinguished Encoding Rules): set of rules how to encode ASN.1 objects/records to binary data. There is also BER (Basic Encoding Rules), which does almost the same, BUT it allows different encoding for the same value (like BOOL can be encoded by any non-zero value), which can not be used in cryptography since the same message can be encoded in different ways, producing different hashes.
- X.509 : standard about format (ASN.1) of public-key certificates.

Hope this helps a bit to understand what's going on :)

Actually, there is a number of cryptography libraries on market, which implement all those timestamping/x.509/signing/verification,etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sad everytime a developer has to do some "deeper" crypto stuff. I know that they are thinking that "he can write code, crypto is just a code that makes something secure, he can do it" and boy it's just wrong. Without solid or almost solid security backgroud crypto-hacking (writing own code) will fail.

I would suggest you to study it, pretty hard because if you do it right it will be ok, but if this fails and some vulnerability is introduced you will have not so nice chats. So I will suggest for starters:

- [Beginning-Cryptography-Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764596330) - even if you are not java person some first chapters
- [Handbook of applied cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)
- [Applied cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)
- [Security engineering](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html)

After those you would get pretty firm grass that crypto is something to be avoided, and only used with extreme caution and only when it does not introduces more problems that it solves.

And About your questions:

- SHA25 - is a cryptographically secure one way hash function that produces 256bit output
- X509 - describes format of digital certificates
- DER and PEM are forms of certificate encodings

And my last request would be that you should not just stop on some high level "I think i got this" point of view and dig deeper and try to really understand what is and what isn't secure.